# Webpacker issues with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

I'm having troubles when pushing on Heroku. Not sure this is it but it seems that it's due to my webpacker.

I posted below all the warning parts of the console

```
...
remote:        warning "babel-loader@7.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "babel-core@6 || 7 || ^7.0.0-alpha || ^7.0.0-beta || ^7.0.0-rc".
remote:        warning "babel-loader@7.1.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@2 || 3".
remote:        warning "compression-webpack-plugin@1.1.3" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^3.1.0".
remote:        warning "file-loader@1.1.6" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has incorrect peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
remote:        warning "sass-loader@6.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "node-sass@^4.0.0".
remote:        warning "sass-loader@6.0.6" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || >= 3.0.0-rc.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.6" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-manifest-plugin@1.3.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@1 || 2 || 3".
remote:        warning "schema-utils@0.4.3" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "ajv-keywords@2.1.1" has incorrect peer dependency "ajv@^5.0.0".
remote:        warning "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^1.9 || ^2 || ^2.1.0-beta || ^2.2.0-rc || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-server@2.11.1" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        warning "webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 29.88s.
...
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/lecoqtrotteur.git
   42bda5b..2a24317  master -> master
```

I'm a newbie and quite lost facing this problem.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey Aurel. What have you done yourself already to try and solve this? It would be helpful to see the config file this is building from.

Comment: Thank you Jon, it was just random syntax issue in my code, I didn't know it could impact production so much :)